# How to run selenium code without eclipse?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cmd, build.gradle

This is my java code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

class mytestclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.sendKeys("selenium!\n"); // send also a "\n"
    element.submit();

    // wait until the google page shows the result
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("resultStats")));

    List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));

    // this are all the links you like to visit
    for (WebElement webElement : findElements)
    {
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    }
  }
}
```

I have entered the following command in cmd to compile the .java file:

```
javac -classpath "selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar;selenium-java-2.53.1\selenium-2.53.1\selenium-java-2.53.1.jar;selenium-java-2.53.1\selenium-2.53.1\selenium-java-2.53.1-srcs.jar;D:\Adit\Selenium\selenium-java-2.53.1\selenium-2.53.1\libs\*.jar" mytestclass.java
```

When I try to run it using 'java mytestclass' it gives me the following error in cmd:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried to use gradle to compile the jar files. My file tree looks like this:
 [image: This is my file tree]

Inside the libs folder highlighted in the image, I have copied all my jar files. I am providing the image below:

[image: JAR files]

My build.gradle file has the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Now, If I give the command 'gradle build' then it says 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'.

```
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.738 secs
```

But then if I try to run the compiled class file using the command 'java mytestclass', I am getting the same error again.

How can I solve it? I want to run selenium without eclipse. I am running windows and my java version is 1.8.0_101.

Comment: remove the double coutes arrond the classpath

Comment: `*.jar` won't work... have you considered using [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) or [maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) to build and manage your dependencies? Both of these build tools have eclipse plugins to share dependencies with eclipse. https://gradle.org/maven_vs_gradle/

Comment: It is still giving the same error. @Jens

Comment: @TahseenAdit exectly same exception?

Comment: As I said... `*.jar` won't work. You'll either need to manually create the the classpath string containing all jars, or use a `.sh`/`.bat` script to append all jar files in a directory to a string. This string can then be passed to `javac`/`java`. As I suggested... these things become much easier with `gradle` / `maven`

Comment: @Jens Yes, exactly the same exception.

Comment: @LanceJava ok I will look at it.

Comment: @LanceJava I have tried as you suggested, But getting the same error again. I have edited my question. Please have a look at it. I am new to gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a libs folder and copied all the jar files from the libs directory of selenium-java-2.53.1 into that newly created libs folder. Then I compiled my java code with Gradle. My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Then I Added two required jar files to the classpath and it solved my problem.